# Showing UI Element with Animation on iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, user-interface

Is there a way to do the following without an instant hide/unhide? Or do I have to make everything a separate view or something complicated? A simple fade in fade out like the modal transition style is all I'm looking for.

```
-(IBAction)someMethod
{
    UIButton.hidden = NO;
    tableView.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIbutton.hidden = YES;
    tableView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could animate the alpha value:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    button.alpha = 0.0f;
    tableView.alpha = 0.0f;
}];
```

and it's counterpart

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    button.alpha = 1.0f;
    tableView.alpha = 1.0f;
}];
```

Comment: Does animate the entire view or just the UIElements?

Comment: Just the elements inside the block. I edited my post to make it more clear.

Comment: can someone explain the ^ symbol programmatically? What is that saying?

Comment: It's called a block - a piece of code that get's executed. Think of it as an anonymous function. Here's the Apple Doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f
                     animations:^ {
UIButton.alpha = 1;
 UIButton.hidden = NO;
tableView.alpha = 1
    tableView.hidden = NO;
                     }];
```

Do the opposite for hide and change the duration to your need.