# Hide/Show Button and UIImageVIew if Tap on a ScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, scrollview

How can I hide/show a `UIButton` and `ImageView` by Tap on a Scrollview?

**EDIT:**

I use this for only Button and Tap on the View:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
   if (!CGRectContainsPoint(btn1.frame, loc) || (!CGRectContainsPoint(btn2.frame, loc)
   {
      btn1.hidden = !btn1.hidden;
      btn2.hidden = !btn2.hidden;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *scrlTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrlTapREcotTap:)];
    [scrlTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self.ScrollView addGestureRecognizer:scrlTap];
```

Take `BOOL isTappFirstTime;` in **.h** file and in `viewDidLoad` method write `isTappFirstTime = YES;`

Write following gesture method;

```
- (void)scrlTapREcotTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
  if(isTappFirstTime)
  { 
       //put code of hide 

     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
           button.alpha = 0;
           imgView.alpha = 0; 
           } completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
             button.hidden = YES;
             imgView.hidden = YES;
      }];        
     isTappFirstTime = NO;
  }
  else 
  {
     // put code of show
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
       button.alpha = 1;
       imgView.alpha = 1; 
       } completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
         button.hidden = NO;
         imgView.hidden = NO;
  }]; 
     isTappFirstTime = YES;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfekt Thanks :) How can I add this fade out?

Comment: what do you mean fade out ??

Comment: that the ImageView and Button "softly" hidden with an nice animation from alpha 1.0 to 0.0

Comment: OK I used your code but "fade out" works perfect, but "fade in" does not work there is no animation

Comment: @Nils check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637711/showing-ui-element-with-animation-on-iphone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047536/fading-in-and-out-uibutton-in-view